# Get pdf file metadata from command line

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, wmic

To get the Creation Date value from a file I would use `wmic` from the command line

`wmic datafile where name="C:\\something.pdf" get CreationDate`

However, I would like to get the Creation (date) value from the pdf file metadata (in reader Files -> Properties). Can I achieve that with a similar approach?

Comment: It is possible with powershell.

Comment: [How can I read out internal pdf creation/modified date with Windows PowerShell?](//superuser.com/q/764513)